# Get Calls Log error

Tags: android, call

I am doing a program for getting call logs, but i have got some problems.
I have got an crash while this program is running, the crash is number format exception invalid int 1415715471534. can anyone fix this?  This is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_satu);
    Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int  number = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int date = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int type = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while(mCursor.moveToNext()){
        String phnNumber = mCursor.getString((int) number);
        String callDuration = mCursor.getString(duration);
        String callType = mCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = mCursor.getString(date);
        Date d = new Date(callDate);
        String callTypeStr = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode){           
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            callTypeStr = "Outgoing";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            callTypeStr = "Incoming";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            callTypeStr = "Missed";
            break;
        }
        sb.append("Phone number" + phnNumber);
        sb.append("Call Duration" + callDuration);
        sb.append("Call type" + callTypeStr);
        sb.append("Call date" + d);
        sb.append("-------------------");
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        mCursor.close();        

    }
    TextView callDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callog);
    callDetails.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: could you post the trace of the exception? what line is the exception?

Comment: when i run it, it crash and give a logcat error : java.lang.NumberFormatException:invalid int:"1415715471534"

Comment: the trace of the exception should give more information: in which line is the error, in which function, etc

Comment: Just use long instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the maximum value that `int` can hold is `2^31-1`. Your value `1415715471534` is more than this. That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: so what should i do? Sorry im still newbie

Comment: can you print the value of `callType` before parsing it? It seems that error might be due to that.